# ERROR CON JSON PARSER

Tags: java, json, app

Estoy enviando un token y un id usuario desde una aplicacion. Están llegando ambos datos, pero necesito hacer un parse y me está devolviendo el siguiente error

```
{"token":"ExponentPushToken[8tR_6cNL20Os__kdVif5Dy]","idUsuario":"11"}

    mar 01, 2019 11:24:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
    GRAVE: El Servlet.service() para el servlet [com.ecodeup.servlet.Servlet] en el contexto con ruta [/notify] lanzó la excepción [La ejecución del Servlet lanzó una excepción] con causa raíz
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.JsonParser
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1363)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1186)
        at com.ecodeup.servlet.Servlet.doPost(Servlet.java:61)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

esto es lo que estoy importando y como lo estoy parseando

```
package com.ecodeup.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
//import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

        StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
        String s;
        while ((s = request.getReader().readLine()) != null) {
            data.append(s);
        }
        System.out.println(data.toString()); //Datos que llegan.
        //data.toString(); //Datos que llegan


        //Gson g = new Gson();

        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(data.toString()).getAsJsonObject();

        String value = jsonObject.get("token").getAsString(); //Token de usuario
        String idUser = jsonObject.get("idUsuario").getAsString(); //ID DEL USUARIO

        String resToken = value.substring(value.indexOf("[") + 1, value.indexOf("]"));
```

Comment: ¿Agregaste GSON al Tomcat?

Comment: Hola, si lo agrego a tomcat funciona. Pero la idea es enviarle todo compilado a un compañero

Comment: Estas utilizando maven o alguna herramienta para hacer tu manejo de dependencias?

Comment: No, no estoy utilizando ninguna herramienta. Quería hacerlo manual